# Aura Integration Error when installing unmanaged package

Tags: error, sandbox, package, unmanaged-package, developer-edition

I've uploaded unmanaged private package from sandbox and trying to install the  package in developer edition but getting below error.

```
Aura Integration Error Service Error[{"message":"An internal server error has occured Error Id:174082486-26226(1182032983)"]
```

**Its been more than 2 hrs that I've uploaded the unmanaged private package.**

Url of Package is  "https://test.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?P0=04tr00000000Vxc"

I've replaced "test" with "Login" from the above url before installing the package in the developer edition

Looks like some known issue. Here is the link
 https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eMp8AAE

Comment: @BorisBachovski I've mentioned in my post that its been more than 2 hrs that I've uploaded the package

Comment: Give it a little bit more time, basically the package is not available yet for installation. I've seen this error before - you get the email with the install URL immediately, though the package is not uploaded or ready to install yet. Also I've noticed the time period varies, so if package doesn't become available soon, I recommend you raise a ticket with Salesforce support.

Comment: Looks like known issue. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eMp8AAE

Comment: I've waited 4 hours before to install a new package from Salesforce.  It honestly just depends on the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like known issue and the release is in progress

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eMp8AAE